# ajax jquery check if error 404 or error 500

Tags: ajax, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-500

I would like to be able to differentiate a 404 error from a 500 error.
In my app I would like to check if either the backend site
returns an error 500 
or if the client has no internet and thus, returns a 404 error

so far I have my call like this

```
$.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: _this.$path_server,
              dataType: 'text',
              crossDomain: true,
              contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
              async: true,
              headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' },
              data:  JSON.stringify(arData),
              cache:false,
              timeout:3000,
              success:function(data,status,text){
                console.log("s data "+data);
                console.log("s status "+status);
                console.log(text);
              },
              error:function(request, status, error){
                console.log("e request ");
                console.log(request);
                console.log("e status "+status);
                console.log("e error "+error);
              },
              fail:function(jqXHR){
                    if(jqXHR.status==500 || jqXHR.status==0){
                        // internal server error or internet connection broke  
                        console.log("fail")
                    }
              },
              getResponseHeader:function(e){
                console.log("get getResponseHeader");
                console.log(e)
              },
               getAllResponseHeaders:function(){
                console.log("get getallResponseHeader");
              },
              statusCode:function(e) {
                    console.log("statusCode func");
                    console.log(e)
                }
            });
```

where _this.$path_server is a link to a php page, which contains
this

```
  <?php
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-type: application/json');
$arr = array('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

if I disconnect my internet connection I have this result from the console

---

jquery-2.0.2.min.js:6 POST [server]/call.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESETx.support.cors.e.crossDomain.send @ jquery-2.0.2.min.js:6x.extend.ajax @ jquery-2.0.2.min.js: e request Object {readyState: 4, responseText: undefined, status: 404, statusText: "error"} e status error e error

Which is fine, no connection is like the php page does not exist, so error 404 it is.

---

but if I intentionally create an error on the php page, in order to create a 500 error, I have this result

jquery-2.0.2.min.js:6 POST [server]/call.php x.support.cors.e.crossDomain.send @ jquery-2.0.2.min.js:6x.extend.ajax @ jquery-2.0.2.min.js
XMLHttpRequest cannot load [server]/call.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
e request 
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: undefined, status: 404, statusText: "error"}
e status error
e error

from that point, the 500 error somehow transform into a 404 error, see status 404. And the 500 error is not triggered by any other error handling I made ( fail or even status error )

So I am unable to differentiate the two error, any help ?
Thanks